# Is cancelling AngularJS $http timeout necessary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm trying to improve my app performance on mobile devices with laggy networks.

The first step was add "global" timeout for all http request, I used simple `request` interceptor for that - `request(config) { return angular.extend({ timeout: 30000 }, config) }`. It worked fine - instead of infinite waiting for the response I could display a warning about laggy network (in the `responseError` interceptor), moreover the slow request is canceled so I can expect that it should free some bandwidth for the other requests.

Now I'm trying to implement another optimization - cancelling pending http requests before the uiRouter state change because there's no reason for loading resources for the state which is no longer going to be displayed. For instance a case when a user is trying to navigate to state A, A resolvables are pending, bored user changed his mind and he's trying to navigate to state B.

My current implementation is base on `$q` and `$timeout` services and custom service for collecting timeouts for all http requests and cancelling them in a batch when necessary. Enough words, here's the code:

```js
const REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 3000; // 30 secs

function httpRequestsCancellerService($timeout, $transitions, $q) {
  const cancelers = [];

  function cancelAll() {
    while (cancelers.length > 0) {
      const canceler = cancelers.pop();
      canceler.resolve();
    }
  }

  // Cancel all pending http requests before the next transition
  $transitions.onStart({}, cancelAll);

  return {
    createTimeout() {
      const canceler = $q.defer();

      // TODO it will keep running even whe the request is completed or failed
      $timeout(canceler.resolve, REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
      cancelers.push(canceler);

      return canceler.promise;
    }
  };
}

function timeoutInterceptor(httpRequestsCanceller) {
  return {
    request(config) {
      const timeout = httpRequestsCanceller.createTimeout();
      return angular.extend({ timeout }, config);
    }
  };
}

module.exports = function($httpProvider, $provide) {
  'ngInject';
  $provide.service('httpRequestsCanceller', httpRequestsCancellerService);
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(timeoutInterceptor);
};
```

It works perfectly now but it has a small drawback - `$timeout` in the `request` interceptor will keep running and it will finally resolve the `canceller` even if the request is completed or failed.

The question is - should I care about these pending `$timeout`s? Is it necessary to `$timeout.cancel` them in order to free some resources or avoid some strange side effects?

Comment: Why is a promise resolved on timeout? Shouldn't it be rejected? A timeout will cause a digest which may be unwanted. I don't see other implications, but they depend on the use. Yes, you can cancel timeouts as well on response.

Comment: According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http is has to be resolved `timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't affect the way the request is rejected. Generally I would recommend against this pattern. There may be nested states that will cause the requests in parent states to be aborted. I'd suggest to handle this on service level instead and trigger service abort in component $onDestroy.

Comment: I don't quite understand. It's perfectly fine when the request in the parent state is aborted (timeouted). In this case resources are not completed and transition to the child state should be aborted, right?

Comment: I mean the opposite case. If you have a request in progress in parent state and make a transition in child state, requests will be aborted in both parent and child states, everywhere. This is an edge case but it shows a flaw in this approach.

Comment: I see now but in this case immediately a new request in the parent state should be made and the transition should be fine providing no timeouts this time.

Comment: Guess it suits your case then.

Comment: Cheers for help!